# How can I search for multiple keywords within the same paragraphs of a text file?

Tags: python, list, keyword

I would like to search in a list whether the combination of two keywords are in the same paragraph of the text to be analyzed.

Example:

I have got a text file and created two lists (`list_a` and `list_b`) consisting of various keywords.  I would like to check whether one keyword of `list_a` and one keyword of `list_b` (it doesn't matter which of these keywords in the list, it is only important that one keyword of `list_a` and one keyword of `list_b`) is found in the same paragraph of my text.

I have tried the following:

1. I splitted my text file into paragraphs

```py
splitted_text = raw_text.split('\n\n')
```

2. I have created a function:

```py
def textContainsKeywords(text, target_words, second_target):
   for target in target_words:
       if target in text:
           for target2 in second_target: 
               if target2 in second_target: 
                  return True
   return False
```

3. I call the function as follows:

```py
target_words = ["residual income", "return on capital employed", "roce", "return on asset", "roa", "return on investment", "roi", "return on"]

second_target = ["weighted average costs of capital", "cost of capital", "cost of equity", "wacc"]

for paragraph in splitted_text:
    if textContainsKeywords(paragraph, target_words, second_target)
        print(paragraph)
```

If I run this code I always receive paragraphs only containing keywords of the "second_target" not of "second_target" AND "target_words". Does somebody have an idea to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Line 4 in your function (`if target2 in second_target:`); shouldn't this be `if target2 in text:`

Answer (score 0):

```
def textContainsKeywords(text, target_words, second_target):
 for target in target_words:
   if target in text:
       for target2 in second_target: 
           if target2 in text: #changes from second__target to text
              return True
return False
```

For your problem try :

```
for paragraph in splitted_text:
   a=bool(textContainsKeywords(paragraph,target_words, second_target))
   if a:
      print(paragraph)
```

Comment: Thank you - thats true! I have corrected it. However, my results display every paragraph in which the second keywords are found and not the combination of one of the first and second keywords. Paragraphs are displayed only containing these words: second_target = ["weighted average costs of capital", "cost of capital", "cost of equity", "wacc"] and not at least one word of this list: target_words = ["residual income", "return on capital employed", "roce", "return on asset", "roa", "return on investment", "roi", "return on"]. What's the problem in my code for this?

Comment: I have edited my answer . Also please upvote and choose the answer if it solves your problems.